# TypeError: Symbol.asyncIterator is not defined. when connecting to AWS amplify

Tags: react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I get this error TypeError: Symbol.asyncIterator is not defined. when connecting to AWS amplify Data model, with React Native. Here's my code;

```
  async function getResraurants() {
    await DataStore.query(Restaurant)
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(e => console.log(e)) //TypeError: Symbol.asyncIterator is not defined. 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getResraurants()
  }, [])
```

I tried different versions of Node.js (current version is 18.13), also tried with expo, but still it gives the same error. Replacing `await DataStore.query(Restaurant)` with an API call (ex. `await axios.get(https://...)`) works fine. The app has amplify Auth, and it works too. Any tips, suggesions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing this package `npm install @azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill`
and import it on the file you're using DataStore `import '@azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill'`

Ref: [Github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8176)

Comment: `npm install@azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill` and then open index.js file and import it. `import '@azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill'`, so it will affect to all the files and you don't need to import in individual files.